# How do I terminate everything at a certain subshell level in Bash, without using "kill 0"?

Tags: bash, process, kill, subshell

**Context:**

Say I have:

```
(
#outer subshell
    {
    #inner command group, pipe-connected to ensure simultaneous invocation
        do_first_thing
        #die, somehow
    } | { 
    #inner command group, pipe-connected to ensure simultaneous invocation
        sleep 10
        do_second_thing
    }
)
echo "out"
```

I have an outer subshell (doesn't have to be one; it can be a command group, or could be removed entirely). Inside that, I have two pipe-connected command groups that get invoked simultaneously. I want both groups to start executing, and then, when the first group finishes (the second will still be `sleep`ing), I want execution *of the outer subshell* to stop, where the `#die, somehow` line is.

**Question:**

What should I do to ensure that when the `#die, somehow` line is reached, everything in the `#outer subshell` level terminates, but execution continues after it (i.e. `out` gets printed)?

**What I've Tried:**

One solution is to use `kill 0` (kill everything in the current process group) to get out of both internal command groups, but then the `echo "out"` will never happen; the whole group will be killed, not just the outer subshell.

I've also tried temporarily overriding and then `unset`ing the `exit` function, but that just seems to push the problem to a different location. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong; I'm by no means a Bash guru.

**Why?**

Without getting into too much detail, the weird subshell-connected command groups are necessary because using `&` to fork out processes does not work deterministically on my system (embedded *nix). As a result, the pipe-connected groups ensure that if `do_first_thing` runs for too long (10 seconds, in the above example), `do_second_thing` will occur. The actual use case is significantly more complex, but this is the root of the problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
(
  #outer subshell                                                                 
  {
    #inner command group, pipe-connected to ensure simultaneous invocation      
    first_step;
    ps -ef | grep './lol.bash' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill;
    #die, somehow                                                           
  } | {
    #inner command group, pipe-connected to ensure simultaneous invocation      
    ./lol.bash;
  }
)
echo "out"
```

and lol.bash contains your sleep and then the so called "second_step"... it's not very clean, but it turns.

an other way is to make a loop in the second part, that check if step one is done, for an amount of time, and then leave if so, or clean all things in first step and does some stuff if time is up...

nb: obviously you can launch at every step a distinct process, and then kill it when you want... (you just need to khnow the pid...)

Answer (score 0):

Would a structure along these lines be suitable?

```
touch /tmp/sentinel-file
(do_first_thing; rm /tmp/sentinel-file) &
pid=$!
sleep 10
if [[ -r /tmp/sentinel-file ]]
then
  kill $pid
  rm /tmp/sentinel-file
  do_second_thing
fi
```

There are some race conditions there if you run multiple copies of this, but in some ways it might be a bit cleaner than what you're doing now.

Comment: If & worked properly, that would work. But it doesn't on my system (see "why" section). If I could properly background things, none of this would be an issue. Thanks!

Comment: Oops... missed that on first reading... In that case, maybe modifying `do_first_thing` to create a file with its PID in it (and removing that file before it exits) so that `do_second_thing` can retrieve the PID to `kill` it might work, assuming you have the source to the programs...

Comment: Not quite; the idea is for the group containing `do_first_thing` to launch *at the same time* as the group containing `do_second_thing`. The first group that finishes (runtime is highly variable, which I represented in the example with a `sleep` statement) shold close the whole outer shell.